# How would we prove by contradiction that there do not exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $15x + 1 = 21y$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would we prove by contradiction that there do not exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $15x + 1 = 21y$?

I have an idea on how to do this (using a factor of $3$ with $21y = 3(7y)$. I am confused with what I am supposed to do to the other side.

Comment: Hint:  $1=21y-15x=3\times (7y-5x)$

Comment: @lulu I appreciate you! Easy question

Comment: Please, choose the tags carefully, this is not a question about probability nor statistics.

Comment: "Not even a week on this platform and I already have Math Karen's in here "  No.  Not even a week on this platform and you have people informing you have the expectations, rules, and culture.  It seems to me anyone who came into a new place and assumes their behavior is the norm is more deserving of the term "Karen" (although "karen" is a revolting and offensive term and no-one deserves it).

Comment: What behaviour? Oh no, I used one too many tags... huge crime I've committed @fleablood                                                                                                                              But I was just joking, I'll keep this in mind so you can sleep peacefully tonight

Comment: If so then by first dupe: $\,21y-15x = 1\Rightarrow 21,15$ are coprime, contra $\,\gcd(21,15)=3\mid 21,15\ $ (this is the easy converse of the Bezout GCD identity).

Answer (score -1):

By doing this:

$15x-21y=1$. Notice that the left side and the right side share no common divisors (except for 1), which implies that no integers $x$ and $y$ can satisfy the given equation. Alternatively, you can divide both sides by $3$ which gives you $5x-7y$ on the left side and one-third on the right side. But that is a contradiction since, no two integers can add up to a fraction.

Comment: Thank you man, legend!

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).